# C++ Compiling - AntiVirus Blocks it - Threat SAPE.Heur.1950

Tags: c++, antivirus, bin

When compiling simple c++ programs with a couple of functions my anti-virus blocks my \bin\debug\name.exe file and claims the threat was SAPE.Heur.1950.  I have tried to bypass it, but does not work.  Wondering if anyone knew what was causing this.  Exact same code in my linux machine works fine.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Add `name.exe` to your antivirus' whitelist.

Comment: Thanks that worked.  I had to manually enter it into the whitelist.  I am not sure why the pop up setting did not suffice.  Thanks again.